# How to left-align code in listing package?

Tags: beamer, spacing, horizontal-alignment, listings

I am working on some slides in beamer about the R language. I use the listing package to show some code. The problem is if I use the autogobble option to remove the unnecessary space, the source code goes over the line numbers. See the pictures below.
[image: Code with unnecessary space and line numbers]

After applying autogobble = true I get:
[image]

How can avoid this issue? The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor = svgnames, handout]{beamer}

%Paquetes basicos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%Paquetes de estilo de la presentacion
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\useoutertheme{varphi}

%Colores personalizados
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray97}{gray}{.97}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

%Paquetes para lenguajes de programacion
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\lstset{
    language = R,
    frame = tb,
    framerule = 0pt,
    aboveskip = 3mm,
    belowskip = 3mm,
    framextopmargin = 3pt,
    framexbottommargin = 3pt,
    framexleftmargin = 0.05cm,
    framexrightmargin = 0.05cm,
    framesep = 0pt,
    rulesep = .4pt,
    backgroundcolor = \color{gray97},
    rulesepcolor = \color{black},
    stringstyle = \color{mauve},
    showstringspaces = false,
    basicstyle = \small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle = \color{dkgreen},
    keywordstyle = \color{blue},
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = -6.5pt,
    numberstyle = \tiny\color{gray},
    numberfirstline = false,
    breaklines = true,
    autogobble=true,
    morekeywords = {*,...}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\textbf{Directorio de Trabajo}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Para fijar el directorio de trabajo:
        \begin{lstlisting}
            setwd("~/Curso R/") 
        \end{lstlisting}
    \item Para obtener el directorio de trabajo:
        \begin{lstlisting}
            getwd()
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving the numbers into the text area with `numbersep = -6.5pt`, you could change the `xleftmargin` to have the numbers aligned with the surrounding text:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor = svgnames, handout]{beamer}

%Paquetes basicos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%Paquetes de estilo de la presentacion
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\useoutertheme{varphi}

%Colores personalizados
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray97}{gray}{.97}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

%Paquetes para lenguajes de programacion
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\lstset{
    language = R,
    frame = tb,
    framerule = 0pt,
    aboveskip = 3mm,
    belowskip = 3mm,
    framextopmargin = 3pt,
    framexbottommargin = 3pt,
    framexleftmargin = 0.7cm,
    xleftmargin=0.7cm,
    framexrightmargin = 0.05cm,
    framesep = 0pt,
    rulesep = .4pt,
    backgroundcolor = \color{gray97},
    rulesepcolor = \color{black},
    stringstyle = \color{mauve},
    showstringspaces = false,
    basicstyle = \small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle = \color{dkgreen},
    keywordstyle = \color{blue},
    numbers = left,
%    numbersep = -6.5pt,
    numberstyle = \tiny\color{gray},
    numberfirstline = false,
    breaklines = true,
    autogobble=true,
    morekeywords = {*,...}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\textbf{Directorio de Trabajo}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Para fijar el directorio de trabajo:
        \begin{lstlisting}
setwd("~/Curso R/") 
        \end{lstlisting}
    \item Para obtener el directorio de trabajo:
        \begin{lstlisting}
            getwd()
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That works for me =).

Comment: @Ramiro You're welcome!